# Can you create a change set in DX?

Tags: salesforcedx

Is it possible to create change set with DX?

One of the things I like about DX is that I put related metadata in a folder. This is great in big orgs. but I'd like to make a Change set from here. The closest I can see is making an unlocked manage like this:
`$ sfdx force:package:create -n YourPackageName -d "Your Package Descripton" -t Unlocked -r force-app`

Answer (score 2):

Changesets aren't something that the core of the SF CLI exposes (at time of writing). I imagine it would be possible for someone to write a plugin for sfdx that can do that, but it doesn't appear anyone has done that yet (at least, not that I can see based on [the awesome sfdx plugins list](https://github.com/mshanemc/awesome-sfdx-plugins).)

`sfdx force:source:deploy` can handle nearly everything that a changeset would offer though, so I don't think there's much incentive to put in the work. The only shortcomings with `force:source:deploy` I could complain about are that we can't specify the Name or provide a description of what the deployment is doing.

Comment: `force:source:deploy` doesn't allow some deployments to Production for me

Answer (score 1):

You can populate a blank changeset that already exists.

- Log into the org and use the UI to create a blank outgoing changeset. Make a note of the name
- In your package.xml, make sure there's a fullName tag at the top and that it matches the changeset name:

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
  `<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">`
  `<fullName>testchangeset</fullName>`
  `<types> ...`
- when you then deploy with `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy`, it will populate the changeset instead of actually deploying

This is based on an existing technique that works with Ant and Workbench, as described here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/320808/4126